# Progress bar for Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, leaflet

How can I show a centered on the map progress bar (with %) while waiting that a layer is rendered on the map?

Here is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.Spin/leaflet.spin.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.Spin/spin.js/dist/spin.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="showMap('http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/landscape/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')">TF.Landscape</a>&nbsp;|<a href="#" onclick="showMap('http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/outdoors/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')">TF.Outdoors</a>
<div id="map" style="width: 640px; height: 480px"></div>
<progress value="0" max="100"></progress> 

<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js"> </script>
<script>
    var map;
    var tileLayer;
    function showMap (layerURL) {
        if(!map) { 
          map = L.map('map').setView([19.5, -73], 7); 
        }

        tileLayer = L.tileLayer(layerURL, {
              attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
              maxZoom: 18
            });
        //map.addLayer(tileLayer);  

        map.spin(true);
            setTimeout(function () {
                map.addLayer(tileLayer);    
                map.spin(false);
           }, 3000);


    }
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is not built- or plugged-in solution for this yet.
So

- if the *progress-bar* and *%* are not that important and you mainly want to tell the user that something's loading you might want to have a look at  [Leaflet.Spin](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.Spin) which is a plugin for showing a spinning icon on your map.
- if you really want a progress-bar a good starting point might be the **markercluster**-plugin. The [50k example](http://leaflet.github.com/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.50000.html) has such a progress bar.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried the leaflet.spin but it does not work. I updated the code.